# How to classify stationary points of a multivariable function?

Tags: calculus

Classify the stationary points of:

$$f(x,y,z) = x^2 + 2y^2 + 3z^2 + 2xy + 2xz$$

I am trying to find all stationary points and whether they are local minimum, local maximum, or saddle.

Comment: You need to look in the right places. How many stationary points are you expecting to find? How would you find a stationary point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: The system of equations
$$
x+y+z=0\\
2y+x=0\\
3z+x=0
$$
looks interesting. So does computing a Hessian.